# Why is Form.Refresh() not working?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm running a data import, using a Windows form to kick off the import and show progress.
I've got this whole thing so nice and user friendly, with major and minor progress bars and everything... but just one problem... the form refresh keeps going AWOL.

I have a call to `Form.Refresh()` every time I update my labels/progress bars, and it usually starts off working.  But if ever I need to break into debug mode, just to hand-hold the import a bit, the `Refresh()` call stops working, and sometimes even if I'm running without Debug mode, at some unpredictable point the same thing happens: the labels and progress bars do not get updated, and if you hide the form and reopen it, the form does not repaint at all - it just shows up entirely white.

Why, oh why, does `Form.Refresh()` stop working, and how can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: I just updated the question for clarity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds as if the import runs on the UI thread, which means that this thread is blocked, preventing the form from repainting itself. A better approach would be to use a `BackgroundWorker` component, do the import in the `DoWork` event handler and use the `ProgressChanged` to update the UI.

Example:

```
private void StartImport()
{
    backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // do some work simulating a lenghy process which occasionally
    // reports progress with data back to the caller
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(i, "Item No " + i.ToString());
    }
}

private void BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    listBox.Items.Add(e.UserState.ToString());
}
```

Using this approach you will typically not need to call `Refresh` to force a repaint of the form.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change your code into using BeginUpdate and EndUpdate, like so:

```
Control.BeginUpdate();
// Do something to the control, e.g. add items or whatnot
Control.EndUpdate();
```

This way Refresh shouldn't be necessary.

AFAIK constantly calling Refresh is really a hack and should be avoiding, as it stresses the CPU quite a bit (it has to refresh everything instead of just the things which are changed).

Edit: If the form starts being white, it seems the drawing code is not been called at all, which indicates it's somewhat not responding.

I'd check the code for anything that can deadlock or otherwisely hang.

Comment: No such method as BeginUpdate or EndUpdate on a C# control...?

Comment: I think it's `myControl.SuspendLayout();` and `myControl.ResumeLayout();`

Comment: It's not available on all controls no, however it is usually for controls which can have children. E.g. Listview.

Could you post the code where you call Refresh ?

Comment: Just added a comment further down the page, I think I finally realize what's happening :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use observer pattern..in short if anything changes in model observer pattern will make sure that change is visible on form..

google it for some examples..

Comment: Please clarify what you mean.  What model is changing?  Why do you think an observer pattern is indicated here?  It's just a progress indicator showing how far the import has got...

Comment: I think I finally understand what you're doing: You have some code running in a loop, and you increment the progressbar inside the loop as well.
Then you call Refresh to reflect the change to the progressbar to the user, right ?

The solution to this is to run the loop in a thread, and just remove Refresh. That way your main thread (which is responsible for drawing) will redraw as required automatically.

Remember to use Invoke when changing the Progressbar from your thread.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what .NET framework you're using, you can use the Task.Run approach:

```
private void btnShowProgress_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = 0;

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            progressBar1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { progressBar1.Value = i; }));                    
        }
    });
}
```

[Task.Run info](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx)

[Using invoke with controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

Answer (score 0):

The solution may not be the best practice but it definitely works for small applications.

In `Form1` create a bool to check to see if the form is closed.

```
public bool formclosed = false
```

Then in `Form2` on the Form Closing Event Handler add

```
formclosed = true
```

also in the `Form2` after

```
InitializeComponent();
```

add

```
formclosed = false;
```

In `Form1` create a timer.

In the `timer1.Tick` event handler say

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(formclosed == true)
        {
            Application.Restart();
        }
    }
```

This will restart the application and refresh everything ... I also had my text saved to the `Properties.Settings.Default` so everytime the application started the default settings would show.

Answer (score 0):

I created an initial version of a Progress control using a BackgroundWorker. The Progress control computed and displayed nice things like Estimated Duration, Estimated Time to Completion. Each statistic was displayed by custom control based on a Label control. The Progress control worked in my production code.

Then I made some changes to the Progress control. I switched from basing my custom statistics controls from Label to Panel. I successfully ran all my tests (using NUnit). Then, I created a Test Windows Forms app. The Progress control successfully worked in the Test Windows Forms app.

When I ran my production Windows app with the updated Progress control it didn't display the statistics.

I tried Thread.Sleep(N), Form.Refresh(). None of those worked to update the statistics.

I eventually called Control.Invalidate() on each Statistic control. The Invalidate caused   OnPaint to be called and the control happily updated the display with its specific statistic.

```
For Each Stat_Obj As Control in Statistics_Controls
    Stat_Obj.Invalidate()
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

You might need to give the window time to redraw itself. I understand you're doing the import in a loop and the loop is running on the main UI thread? Try adding this line to the loop:

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

Comment: OMG that's even more hackish than calling Refresh all the time, seriously Sleep is almost NEVER a solution.

Comment: Agree with Steffen: also, if the import is running on the UI thread (which I get the impression that it is) this will still block that thread, preventing the redraw from happen anyway.

Comment: Steffen's comment is correct. It's horribly hackish - and it doesn't work, either.  I know, I tried... (blushes)... :)

Comment: Oh, well, you're all correct, apologies. In my defense I thought the loop is happening on the worker thread. Sometimes even though it's a separate thread the app doesn't have enough time to redraw itself.

Comment: -1 Sorry, still every bit as hackish as Thread.Sleep().  Look at the answer I've accepted for the right way to do this.

Comment: THIS solution worked GREAT for me in my unit tests so +1 !!!!!  I am using NUnitForms and I just stick App.DoEvents now in between stuff I want refreshed.  The SuspendLayout/ResumeLayout didn't work at all and I am not sure how to implemenet the backgrounder thing which is using a control and my tests only have access to forms, plus this solution just seems easy AND I only stick it in the unit tests not in the code anyways as the code works fine when refreshing stuff...just not in debug mode.